# How to pass variables to fragment from activity when fragment is initialized by layout file (not programmatically)?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating an Amazon Fire TV app and decided to use the already provided resources by Android Studio when I started a new project and chose the Android TV option. In this project, the Main Activity sets the content view to activity_main.xml, and activity_main.xml initializes the MainFragment class like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name="com.morega.amazonfiretv.mota.ui.MainFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

In my MainActivity, I'm a loading some resources from the network and setting them to some member variables. These member variables are defined as public static variables (I'm building this app off a tablet version of the app, thus using the same back end to it and not trying to make too many changes). How do I access these member variables from my MainFragment class? I'm still learning OOP and don't fully understand the difference between static and non-static variables so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You can use the method given as an answer below or you can use interfaces. Create an interface class in your fragment. Let your activity implement it. You can pass whatever values you want via your interface from your fragment to the activity. Let me know if you use this approach and have questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, you can use:

```
MainFragment mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_browse_fragment)
```

So you have a reference to your fragment that is inflated by XML.

Then you can create a public function in your fragment like so:

```
public void setData(String data)
```

and call it from your activity, when you have completed the network request.

```
mainFragment.setData(data);
```

That should handle all the variables in a proper manner.

Comment: Why am I getting a 'Cannot Resolve method' message for getSupportFragmentmanager() ? I've imported the android.app.Fragment package in my MainActivity.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() *

Comment: Some more info on my activity, right now I had it as MainActivity extends Activity, while my MainFragment extends BrowseFragment (which is a class in the leanback.app package used for Android TV apps)

Comment: @JvalantDave If you aren't using support library fragments, just use `getFragmentManager()` instead.